# get current admins from database

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am using **laravel** to create a website for my youth movement. I currently have three tables set up for my roles: `Users`, `Roles` and `role_user`. They look as following:

```
+-------+     +-------+     +-----------+
| Users |     | Roles |     | role_user |   
+-------+     +-------+     +-----------+
| id    |     | Id    |     | user_id   |
| Name  |     | Name  |     | role_id   |
+-------+     +-------+     | start     |
                            | stop      |
                            +-----------+
```

The `user_role` table is a pivot table between `users` and `roles`. A user can be in a certain role for a certain time defined from `role_user.start` until `role_user.stop`.

I am trying to create a function in my `User` model to check if a user is an admin, this is either a user role 1 or 2, but a user can have more roles as well.
I have already tried different ways of achieving this, but it is getting way to complicated and it never works.

The relationships have been made correctly, I am sure of this because I use them in other functions as well.

For example: 
**User.php:**

```
/**
 *  Find the roles for this user.
 */
public function user_roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Role')->withPivot('start', 'stop');    
}
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance,
Jerodev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you always want all roles between `start` and `stop`, you can add a few `where()`'s to your relationship.

```
public function user_roles()
{

    $now = \Carbon\Carbon::now();

    return $this->belongsToMany('Role')->withPivot('start', 'stop')->where('start', '<', $now)->where('stop', '>', $now);

}
```

Additionally, you can do a lot more with `Carbon`'s methods:

```
\Carbon\Carbon::now()->subDays(2);
```

Depending on you're format of timestamp in `start` and `stop`, you may need to format `$now` properly.

Comment: Thanks, I added a new function called `current_user_roles` with these filters and it worked fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

Given the tables you pasted, your relationship is not correct. It lacks table name (Eloquent looks for `role_user` by default).

So either this is the name of that pivot table, or it does not work, and you should have:

```
public function user_roles()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('Role', 'user_role');
}
```

Anyway, to get your admins:

```
public function adminRoles()
{
  $now = \Carbon\Carbon::now();

  return $this->belongsToMany('Role')
    ->wherePivot('start', '>=', $now)
    ->wherePivot('stop', '<=', $now)
    ->wherePivot(function ($q) {
      $q->whereIn('role_id', [1,2]);
    })
    ->withPivot('start', 'stop');
}
```

You can alternatively use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` instead of Carbon.

Of course this is not the best solution, since roles are hard-coded. So adjust it to meet your needs.

Then to select admin users:

```
User::has('adminRoles')->get();
```

Comment: Oh, sorry, my bad, the relationship does work, I used the wrong name here.

Comment: That's what I thought. Anyway, mind that you should use `wherePivot` instead of `where` in case there is fields names collision (on related table and pivot table). For example `created_at`, `updated_at` etc.